# creating a button on and off and running

Tags: python, python-3.x

newbie here i am creating a button that will print out

the button is on 
the button is running
the button is off

so far I have done the code below but it keeps saying the self is not defined...

```
class FireAlarm(self):
    def __init__(self, ringing):
        self.ringing = True

    def firealarmringing
        self.ringing = True

    def firealarmisstopped
        self.ringing = False

    def firealarmisringing
        self.ringing = True

print(str("the alarm is" + FireAlarm(self)))
```

Comment: Most of your functions miss the parameter definition

Comment: You should read and work through the introductory Python tutorial. The code you presented contains many elementary syntax errors.

Comment: can you tell me a good website where i can do python tutorials like freecodecamp .. with exercises?.